# Normaly distributed variables vector

Tags: r, distribution, normal-distribution

I don't know how to make a sample of 100 variables. Each is distributed normally. First one: X1 is distributed normally with (mi,1), the next one: X2 is distributed normally with parameters (X1,1), X3 is distributed normally with parameters (X2,1)  and so on...each variable is distributed normally with parameter that is previous variable and 1

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do here. The first parameter here is the mean, but you say `(X1,1)`... do you mean the mean of `X1`? If so, have you tried the `rnorm` function combined with `mean`, and then maybe a for-loop? It would be really useful if you could provide some example data, ideally with a piece of code that you tried to use yourself, and the expected output.

Comment: I would suggest that you have a look at the [`mvtnorm`](http://math.furman.edu/~dcs/courses/math47/R/library/mvtnorm/html/Mvnorm.html) package and the function `rmvnorm`.

Comment: Assuming that you are interested in passing some parameters from the previously generated variable to the next one you could do this in a simple loop:`dta <- as.data.frame(x = runif(n = 10))
for(i in 2:10) { dta[,i] <- rmvnorm(n = 10, mean = mean(dta[,i-1]))}`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'm completely new to R and don't know how to deal with it yet.

Comment: Laterow, yes, I mean the mean of X1

Comment: the first mean forr X1 is given: it's 27

Comment: I now have:                    library(mvtnorm)
         
sigma <- 1
mi <- 27
X1 <- rnorm(100, mi, 1)


dta <- as.data.frame(x = runif(n = 100))

for(i in 2:100)
{ 
  
dta[,i] <- rmvnorm(n = 100, mean = mean(dta[,i-1]))
}                        But I don't know if it is right.

Comment: Sounds like an AR(1) process, except with coefficient 1 it's not going to be stationary.